# Codeigniter form - hidden field not filled with variable

Tags: forms, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm having a little problem regarding a CI Form:

I retrieve some entries from the db and put them in hidden fields in my form. One of the values isn't filled into the hidden field, even though I can verify it's there:

```
    <?php 
        echo $grno;
        echo $dsca;
        $hidden = array(
            'grno' => $grno,
            'dsca' => $dsca,
            'bsex' => 'männlich',
            'noch' => '0',  
            ....
```

the echo statement shows both values in the view but the hidden field that is supposed to be filled with the value of $grno is empty..

Any ideas? 
Thanks a lot, this is driving me crazy...

Regards 
Lutz

Comment: how u using in form?

Comment: that's really weird.

Comment: Can you post your controller function code? So for the view code as well?

Comment: please put full code

Comment: Nevermind, it was a classic 2'oclock at night brain malfunction...